# overloaded constructor js (function initialization)

Tags: javascript, class

I have a JavaScript class with a given constructor, and I want the user to be able use function to instantiating an object. An example of what I pretend could be the following:

```
class Car{
    constructor(numberWheels, Name, Color){
        this.wheelsNum = numberWheels;
        this.name = Name;
        this.color = Color;
   }
}
```

Create a function, which used  Car constructor. After use this function, i write string keys from object car: like this function () let car2 = new Car ('numberWheels', 'Color'); and after this create new object with this keys.

```
let car1 = new Car (4, 'jeep', 'red');
function ()
let car2 = new Car ('numberWheels', 'Color');
let car22= new Car2(4, 'yellow');
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. What are you asking?

Comment: Create a function, that modifier  Car constructor. After use this function, i write string keys from object car: like this `function ()
let car2 = new Car ('numberWheels', 'Color');` and after this create new object with this keys.

Answer (score 0):

To create nameless cars, you can create a separate function:

```
function car2(numberWheels, color) { return new Car(numberWheels, undefined, Color); }
const car22 = car2(4, 'yellow');
console.log(car22);
```

No, you cannot create this function by passing strings to the constructor, and you really shouldn't.